# How do I return values from certain type of array list?

Tags: java, class, printing, getter

Is this program doable with just getters or print statements, or should I consider doing it differently?

If what I'm doing is using essentially a getter with no constructor, that doesn't make sense to me. So, I believe it would make more sense from the standpoint of a print statement. I'm also assuming I don't need to make a new class.

I think if it was really that easy, the exercise would have been earlier in the textbook:

Exercise 129:

In the program fragment below, each of the employees in the employee database is stored in an ArrayList. Complete the program so that the names of all the employees are output.

```
public class MainClass
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

employees.add( new Teacher( "Fred Thompkins", 55, 525 ) );
employees.add( new SalesAssistant( "Eric Washington", 7, 72 ) );
employees.add( new Military( "Albert Costa", 236237, "Navy", "Seaman" ) );
employees.add( new Teacher( "Jane Austin", 724, 92 ) );
employees.add( new SalesAssistant( "Jane Black", 91, 295 ) );
employees.add( new Employee( "Scott Black", 23 ) );
employees.add( new SalesPartTime( "Janice Dell", 552, 501, 8.0 ) ); 

    for ( Employee e : employees )

    {



    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ur question is how to iterate the employees object which contain sub-classes of Employee class ??

Answer (score 2):

It's as simples as that. You just have to create a getter for the name, and print it.

```
for ( Employee e : employees )
{
    System.out.println(e.getName());
}
```

Alternatively, you can override the `toString` method of `Employee`

```
@Override 
public String toString() {
     return this.name;
}
```

And then, you could call

```
for ( Employee e : employees )
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you answered your own question. You can do this just by getters. If you have a `getName` like method in `Employee`(superclass) class then the below code will work perfectly

```
for ( Employee e : employees ) {
    System.out.println(e.getName());
}
```

Comment: That still didn't work. Do you mean like this:

    public string getEmployee{

        return Employee;

    }

Comment: separated into different lines?

Comment: Do you have any method to return the employee name?

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it. If you click on "show details" in the textbook, it shows you that there's already a "getName" method. I just needed to call it from the editable part, within the for-loop.

```
    for ( Employee e : employees )

{
    System.out.println(e.getName());
}
```

Or something like that.

Anyways, that was all that was really needed. Lol, it was so much more simple than I thought it would be.

Comment: That's actually what the answers say. You should accept the most correct answer instead of coming here and saying that it solved your problem in a new answer.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted click on check mark under the score of the question. This will give reputation to you and the person who answered correctly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work